# Sound does not play on device [Titanium]

Tags: ios, audio, titanium, playback

I am using the following code to play sound. The sound works correctly on the simulator but does not work on the device. Both of the devices are running the same iOS version.

Is there a way to debug this error ? How can I fix this ?

```
var soundLabel = Ti.UI.createView({
backgroundColor:'red',
width:125,
height:40,
top:75,
right:340
});




 soundLabel.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   var sound = Titanium.Media.createSound();
  sound.setUrl("/Sound/"+alphabet+".wav");  
    alert("HERE");
    sound.play();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following line just above your line `sound.play();`

`Titanium.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_PLAYBACK;`

Please have a look at [Ti.Media.Sound.play() no sound on iPhone speaker, works only on headphones](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143765/timediasoundplay-no-sound-on-iphone-speaker-works-only-on-headphones). I think you may also have same issue.